# Conditional matching not working with perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have to write a regex to match the below strings and extract the year

**Copyright 2015 or Copyright 2014-2015**

I have written the regex given below and trying to execute the code in a perl program

```
Copyright\s+(?(?=\d+\s*-\s*\d+)(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)|(\d+))
```

The regex given above matches the string **Copyright 2014-2015** but fails when the string is **Copyright 2015**. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me. How are you testing it? And why not simply `/Copyright\s+(\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?/`?

Comment: @Сухой27: Why are you editing it to PCRE? Perl and PCRE are different.

Comment: @nhahtdh there is no perl code, it looks regex only related.

Comment: @Сухой27 If OP tagged it as Perl I'd say that's enough reason to assume it is Perl.

Comment: I am saving the regex in a variable and trying to retrieve it as given below but I dont get the matched string.

`($firstmatch, $secondMatch) = $string =~ m/$COPYRIGHT_PATTERN/g;`

Comment: @moiz134 The lone `2015` would be captured in group 3.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked. I was not printing all groups which caused the issue. My apologies and thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is working:

```
Copyright\s+(?(?=\d+\s*-\s*\d+)(\d+)\s*-\s*(\d+)|(\d+))
```

Matches: Copyright 2015 in capturing group 3
Matches: Copyright 2014-2015 in capturing group 1 and 2

---

```
Copyright\s+(\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+))?
```

Matches: Copyright 2015 in capturing group 1
Matches: Copyright 2014-2015 in capturing group 1 and 2

Comment: Thank you, I was not capturing all groups. **Embarrassed**

Comment: @Andie2302 You might want to throw some `\s+` and `\s*` in there to mimic OP's regex. (`[0-9]` vs `\d` is another discussion.)